# When using CassandraStorage() in Pig, cannot cast NonSpillableDataBag to DefaultDataBag

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

My Pig code has the line

> STORE FOO INTO "cassandra://..." using CassandraStorage();

I have my data formatted as a value followed by a bag of tuples (CassandraStorage complained about format until I did that). Now when I run my Pig script, I get the error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.NonSpillableDataBag
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.DefaultDataBag  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage.putNext(CassandraStorage.java:520)

Any suggestions? Note that I used Pig Latin's TOBAG function to create the bag.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this is a bug in Cassandra 1.2. I was able to fix it by replacing all of the occurrences of DefaultDataBag with DataBag in org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage (except of course where the code said new DefaultDataBag()) and then rebuilding Cassandra 1.2.